# Backbone Paginator: overall add event (not triggered multiple times)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-paginator

I am using Backbone Paginator. It's `requestNext()` method will get a list of items from the server, and trigger an "add" event.

However the add event is triggered for each and every item added into the collection. I want to have an event that is only triggered for each success page request. Is there a build-in way, or how can I make such a custom event?

Comment: i have the same problem, i bind render on collection add and remove, this behaviour cause the view to be rendered 30 times on first fetch